# Xamarin Forms two ListView vertically side by side

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a similar UI as the attached photo.

[side by side vertical list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXNMU.jpg)

[Watch it in action](https://ibb.co/MpNrFyr)

So far I have the following code snippet working on Android perfectly, but on iOS, the first listview doesn't scroll unless I rotate the screen.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
        <ListView Grid.Column="0" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MyCategories}"                       
                  RowHeight="200" ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected" Scrolled="ListView_Scrolled"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="50*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="50*"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="icon.png"></Image>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding SelectedCategory.Name}" FontSize="Title" />
            
            <ListView Grid.Row="1" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCategory.SubCategories}"                       
                  RowHeight="150" SeparatorColor="Green"
                  >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="50*"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="50*"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="icon.png"></Image>
                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: you can use master detail pages for purposes like this

Comment: What do you mean by  the first listview doesn't scroll? I saw the gif and you scrolled the first list successfully.

Comment: sorry should have been more clear, the gif was an example from an existing app.